# Loop through 4 post types and only return 1 post per type

Tags: loops, custom-post-type, wordpress

I'm trying to understand the most efficient way to return 4 most recent posts. 1 from each post type. There are 4 post types.

I could do several things such as 4 different queries. Or count each post within each post type returned, then only allow the first to display. But everything I'm coming up with seems really overcomplicated.

Here is what I have so far, returning 4 posts of whatever post types are recent

```
    <?php 
        $newsArgs  = array(
            'posts_per_page'  => 4,
            'orderby'         => 'post_date',
            'order'           => 'DESC',
            'post_type'       => array('post', 'news', 'press', 'casestudy'),
            'post_status'     => 'publish',
            'suppress_filters' => true,
        );

        $query = new WP_Query( $newsArgs );
        if ( $query -> have_posts()) {
            while ( $query -> have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php the_title(); ?>

           <?php endwhile;
        }

        wp_reset_postdata(); 

    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: 4 more recent from 4 post type meaning ? is it 4 from each of the 3 categories ? is it 4 with unique one from each category ? is it total 4 of absolute last posts by time but can have three from one category and one from another omitting other two ?

Comment: @ObmerkKronen My apologies, that was worded pretty badly. I've rewritten it to be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without creating a custom query to handle this (which in itself is going to be VERY ugly to look at), Wordpress doesn't have much in the way of supporting that without at least than 4 or 5 separate queries per request.... [very expensive](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/NWQqCzGbeik/maxresdefault.jpg)

To ensure you get at least one of each post type without too much care about performance, you can do something like this:

```
$results = array();
foreach(array('post', 'news', 'press', 'casestudy') as $type){
    $post = get_posts(array(
        'posts_per_page'  => 1,
        'post_type'       => $type,
        'post_status'     => 'publish'
    ));
    $results[] = $post[0]->ID;
}
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'suppress_filters' => true,
    'post__in'         => $results
));
if ( $query -> have_posts()) {
    while ( $query -> have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php endwhile;
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

It's untested, but it should help get you to where you need.

Comment: A 'Doug' reference! Interesting code, so I basically would have to do 4 queries..?

Comment: Or come up with a custom query via [WPDB](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb). A custom WPDB query would be less expensive, but likely less readable and harder to manage. Another possibility would be to boil news and press back down to post categories if their respective structures don't vary too much, but that's entirely dependent on your theme and internal processes. This code ends up running 5 queries per request in total, 1 for each post type request, and a final one to sort the results by date. It's not ideal, but it's a possibility.